# Prompt error when calling method of install_app() with uiautomator2

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, python-appium

I met a error when initialize appium setting success, then call install_app() method to reinstall a new app.

Comment: error as below:WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined

Comment: File "run.py", line 54, in test
    driver.install_app(path_apk+'//apk//'+newName)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 511, in insta
ll_app
    self.execute(Command.INSTALL_APP, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 29, in che
ck_response
    raise wde

Comment: occur script is: driver.install_app(path of apk)

Comment: with calling method 'os.popen('adb install path of apk')' instead

Comment: did you found a solution?